# How to use a variable offset in inline assembly?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

The overall problem I am trying to solve, is to call printf, while fetching its format string and arguments from a raw buffer. So far, the solution that seems to be working the best is through the use of inline assembly as a way to pass the mixed typing variadic arguments to the function.

Currently we have chars and ints working flawlessly, and floats/doubles working up until we need to pass them on the stack. (Passing through xmm0 - xmm7 works flawlessly for us). The goal here is to push these floating point values to the stack once xmm0-xmm7 have all been used. These values would then be used in the subsequent call to printf. The way we handle this for the chars and ints is to push them onto the stack just by simply using the `push` instruction, which the call to printf is able to use just fine, but since that instruction doesn't work for floating point values we have to manually 'push' it onto the stack with the method below. I realize that this is very likely to be the wrong way to handle this, but we haven't been able to figure a way out of doing it this way.

Currently our solution to passing more than eight floating point values on the stack requires us to know the offset of the argument that is being passed to our printf call. In this case the offsets correspond to 8 byte increments. The 9th argument is to be loaded into `(%rsp)`, the 10th into `0x8(%rsp)` the 11th into `0x10(%rsp)` the 12th into `0x18(%rsp)` with the rest of the arguments continuing this trend.

My goal with this "variable offset" is to just reduce the amount of repeated code that handles the incremented offset. Currently it just checks which argument is being processed, and jumps to the hardcoded constant offset. But this has led to a lot of duplicated code, which I was hoping to clean up.

Below is a small snippet of what we are doing currently to move one of the arguments into its appropriate place for the call to printf to access the argument.

```c
double myDouble = 1.23;
asm volatile (
  "movsd %0, 0x8(%%rsp)" #The 0x8 is the offset we are hoping to pass in
:: "m" (myDouble)
);
```

I am looking for a way to store this offset (0x8, 0x10, 0x18,...) in a variable that can be incremented by eight as I process the arguments, though I now fear that this will break once we start mixing in more mixed typed values that are pushed onto the stack.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please explain what you mean with “offset.”  Off what is that offset set?  Where is that “specific location?”  Why can't you use an `"m"` class input or output operand to access memory?

Comment: Also, the displacement (i.e. `0x8` in `0x8(%rsp)`) is always a constant, so I don't quite understand how that is supposed to be variable.  I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do.  Perhaps explain the big picture so I can try to find a solution to the problem you try to solve with your “variable offset” idea.

Comment: You are also trying to move from a memory address to a memory address which won't work (x86 doesn't have any instructions that specify an explicit memory operand for both source and destination). Why do you want to move something to memory relative to RSP in inline assembly this way? What problem are you trying to solve in doing so. If we knew what you were really trying  to achieve with inline assembly here might be able to help us provide a better solution for what your real problem is. This does smell like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: I've added some more details about the overall problem I am attempting to solve to the post. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @MDausch I wonder if you are making your own life much more difficult than needed.  Why don't you call `printf` multiple times instead of trying to do half the work of the libffi yourself?

Comment: You can emulate `push low_qword(xmm0)` by using `sub $8, %rsp` / `movsd %xmm0, (%rsp)`.  I don't get why you're introducing offsets into this.  The whole thing sounds like a horrible nasty hack, especially for x86-64 System V.  For Windows x64 it's much simpler because the calling convention is designed to make variadic functions easy.

Comment: I think my approach would be to parse the format string into single argument parts and iterate over that. I think that's what @fuz is suggesting, too.

Comment: @Chris & Fuz I had thought about that, but was initially thrown off about how to do some of the tokenizing for it, but now that I think more about it, it doesn't seem as bad as I had initially thought. I was put onto this project with a decent part of it already done, so its what I was initially going off of. Maybe I can persuade them to let me go with this route instead haha. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Why not use `vprintf`?

Comment: @TimothyBaldwin This was something I had toyed around with for a little bit, but was unable to get working. I could not figure out how to get my buffer into a `va_list`

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible using the instruction with a constant offset. To generate the code, the offset would need to be known at compile time, and not be variable. You have to use a different instruction, an indirect load with base register and offset:

```
int foo(int64_t offset, double value)
{
    asm volatile (
        "movsd %0, (%%rsp,%1)" :: "x" (value), "r" (offset)
        : "memory"
    );
}
```

You could also let the CPU do the multiplication by 8 by using a scaled offset addressing mode:

```
int foo(int64_t offset, double value)
{
    asm volatile (
        "movsd %0, (%%rsp,%1,8)" :: "x" (value), "r" (offset)
        : "memory"
    );
}
```

---

Or if you want to emulate `push`, then `sub $8, %%rsp` / `movsd %0, (%%rsp)`, but you can't mess with the stack pointer from inline asm without breaking compiler-generated code.

Comment: *Note that this might well segfault if offset is not a multiple of 8* No, `movsd` doesn't do alignment checking, only `movaps` / `movapd` / `movdqa` (and 16-byte memory operands for legacy-SSE instructions).  GCC code-gen assumes that the `AC` (alignment-check) bit is unset; it will freely load or store two narrow variables with one instruction, even if that might be unaligned.

Comment: You forgot to use a `"memory"` clobber here.  See [How can I indicate that the memory \*pointed\* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](//stackoverflow.com/q/56432259) - that's not implied. 
 Also, you need to cast `offset` to `int64_t` to make sure it's correctly *sign*-extended to 64-bit.  `int` is 32-bit, and the upper bytes of the register can be holding garbage.  Typically they'll be zero-extended (which is not what you want either for signed int), but they can be any garbage.  I would have said `intptr_t`, but that's a 32-bit type on the ILP32 x32 ABI, and you're using 64-bit RSP

Comment: Also, `"m"(value)` is broken.  x86 can't do 2 explicit memory operands for one instruction, and this will compile to something like `movsd  -16(%rsp), (%rsp, %rdi)` after spilling the function arg from XMM0 to stack memory.  Use an `"x"(value)` XMM register constraint.

Comment: @PeterCordes all correct. My point was the necessary use of `(%rsp, %rxx)` instead of `0x8(%rsp)`, but I should have written that as a comment instead of posting non-working code.

Comment: Oh also, if the offset *is* available at compile time, you could use `if(__builtin_constant_p(offset))` to use a version of the asm like `%c1(%rsp)` to use the offset as a displacement instead of putting it into a register first.